# Using a while loop walrus operator with a generator

Tags: python, generator, python-3.8, walrus-operator

I'd like to use a walrus operator with a simple generator in a while loop

```py
def gen():
    for i in range(5):
        yield i
    yield 10


g = gen()

while i := next(g):
    print(i)
```

I expect the output to be:

```
0
1
2
3
4
10
```

However it's not printing anything. I'm aware I can do this in a for loop:

```py
for i in gen():
  print(i)
```

I'm not interested in the output being exact. I want a simple example of using generators with walrus operators.

Comment: What happens when you run it?

Comment: The first element emitted from your `gen()` is zero, so the while condition is immediately false, and the loop ends.

Comment: Note you can just do `for i in g: print(i)`.

Comment: Thanks @khelwood good spot!

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was looking to create the most simple generator with a walrus operator example

Answer (score 3):

This loop:

```
while i := next(g):
    print(i)
```

will iterate through each element of your generator and print it, until one of them is falsey. Since your generator emits 0 as its first element, the while condition is immediately false, and the loop  ends without printing.

But if, for example, your iterator was:

```
g = iter([2,1,0,2,5])
```

then your loop would print 2 and 1, and stop when it received the value 0.

---

If you want to iterate through all the elements until it runs out of elements, just use:

```
for i in g:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Would be good to include an example that works to show how to use them together properly

Answer (score 1):

gen() is returning 0 on the first iteration. range(1, 5) to set range to go from 1 to 5. I also updated 10 to None else the generator runs out and throws Ex

```
def gen():
    for i in range(1, 5):
        yield i
    yield None


g = gen()

while i := next(g):
    print(i)
```

output:

```
1
2
3
4

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: This is a great simple example thanks @testfile

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using a `while` loop you need the condition to be `True`. The first element that is returned is `0`. Which is interpreted as `False`.

If you **need** the `:=` operator, use:

```
try:
    while (i := next(g)) or i == 0:
        print(i)
except StopIteration:
    # This executes when the generator is exhausted
    pass
```

Or use `range(1, 10)`, so `0` is never returned

---

If you are open to changes, please use:

```
for i in g:
    print(i)
```

Or you avoid the removal of `g`'s assignment, and do:

```
for i in gen():
    print(i)
```

Comment: This isn't as clean as testfiles answer but thanks! 

I was looking to implement the most simple example of using a generator possible with the walrus operator

Comment: No worries Harry. using a for loop is cleanest (and most preffered), note that testfile's answer doesn't allow for the original range of `0, 10`

Comment: Yeah I was just playing with the most simple generator possible, I'm not interested in the actual program printing the correct results.